# Duplicates or copy a div after clicking a button in php, still cant figure out

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was developing or creating a website which will intendedly use by an organization. 
Specifically i have one problem in the registration form of a member.
A member must have 3 or more committees to be standing to. In my previous work i have created that in a checkbox but unfortunately i have a hard trouble in doing that. Then i have thinking of this and i know that someone knows this even though i have done a bit of research.
Here is the sample of the div taht i am talking about.
                Add Choices

```
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
           <select type="text" name="e_squestion" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="font-size:12px; height:30px;">
                <option value=''>* Security Question *</option>
                <option value='1'>Internal Rules and Privileges</option>
                <option value='2'>Appropriations Finance and Budget</option>   
                <option value='3'>Agriculture and Cooperatives</option> 
                <option value='4'>Environmental Protection, Natural Resources and Disaster Risk Reduction Management</option>                      
                <option value='5'>Education</option>   
                <option value='6'>Tourism, Culture and Special Events</option>   
                <option value='7'>Zoning and Rural Development</option>
                <option value='8'>Good Government, Public Ethics and Accountability</option>   
                <option value='9'>Ways and Means</option>   
                <option value='10'>Women and Family and Social Services</option>   
                <option value='11'>Human Rights, Peace & Order and Public Safety</option>  
                <option value='12'>Public Works</option>   
                <option value='13'>Health and Public Sanitation</option> 
                <option value='14'>Trade, Labor, Commerce & Industry</option> 
                <option value='15'>Public Utilities</option> 
                <option value='16'>Barangay Affairs</option> 
                <option value='17'>Public Market & Slaughterhouse</option> 
          </select>
          </div>
```

I am planning what if a member will just select for a committee that he/she will stand and if he/she has 3 more committee to stands he/she will just click the button above three times and there you go div's with a select option will appear together with a button beside it to close it the member wants to remove any of it.
Im just asking for a help from other people, and im looking forward to thank you for anyone that would help me.
Thanks a lot. Peace. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts that you need to solve:

1. Front-end duplication of the select tag. This is easily done using jQuery or any other library, you can simple `var select = $("select").clone();` and then `$("#container-of-selects").append(select);`
2. You need to change the `name` attribute of the select tag to `e_squestion[]`: this will allow you to send all the selected options as 1 array that you can save. You'll have access to `e_squestion` param from PHP (either $_POST or whatever framework you're using).

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate your answer sir. Im a little bit busy in other things sir. But tomorrow ill try to practice and apply what you have said sir. Thank you very much sir. ( sorry for my redundant "sir" i am more likely to respect other people especially to those who help other people to. Thank you again sir.